# How to merge these two forEach loops (use only one)?

Tags: javascript, loops

The followning code takes two arrays (`fields` and `photos`), get the name and value of their fields, and add them to a new array (`panoramas`):

**Function:**

```
const panoramas = this.uploads.finished.map(photos => {
   let panorama = {}
   fields.forEach(field => { panorama[field.name] = field.value })
   photos.forEach(photo => { panorama[photo.name] = photo.value })
   return panorama
})
```

**Input:**

`fields`:

```
[{
  name: "name"
  type: "hidden"
  value: ""
}, {
  name: "description"
  type: "hidden"
  value: ""
}, {
  name: "photo"
  type: "file"
  value: ""
}, {
  name: "photo2"
  type: "file"
  value: ""
}]
```

`photos`:

```
[{
  name: "photo"
  value: "1.png"
}, {
  name: "photo2"
  value: "2.jpg"
}]
```

Output:

`panoramas:`

```
[{
  name: "name"
  type: "hidden"
  value: ""
}, {
  name: "description"
  type: "hidden"
  value: ""
}, {
  name: "photo"
  type: "file"
  value: "1.png"
}, {
  name: "photo2"
  type: "file"
  value: "2.png"
}]
```

As you can see I'm using two `forEach` loops inside `map`. Is there a way to use just one `forEach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fields.concat(photos).forEach(obj => { panorama[obj.name] = obj.value });
```

Comment: Yo're a genius! (Or maybe I'm too dumb.)

Comment: Highly doubt both assertions XD.

Comment: this output is not the question wanted.

Comment: How so? With this answer the user only has to run one `forEach`.

Comment: I'll take your word. Not sure what the discrepancy is in the post before last.